# Comparison operator giving idiosyncratic result in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

A friend of mine today told me to open the Chrome Console and see the output for three JavaScript commands that I report here below (with the corresponding output).

```
> Boolean([])
< true
> Boolean("")
< false
> [] == ""
< true
```

When I told him that it was probably a bug, he replied that it is a famous thing and a JavaScript developer should know about it.

Is it true? Is there any logic that justifies the output seen above or it is just a bug of the language?

Comment: https://dmitripavlutin.com/the-legend-of-javascript-equality-operator/

Comment: type casting...

Answer (score 2):

To compare `[]` and `""`, JavaScript tries to bring them to same type, in this case: String.

You'll notice a similar result with this (and it makes sense to us):

```
[].toString() == "" // true
```

Comment: Exactly, even `[1, 2, 3] == "1,2,3"` is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

Wow! What a great question! This is such crazy behavior when coming to JavaScript from a different language right? Or heck, even if JavaScript is your first language it's still crazy. But it is indeed the language working as intended.

There's an amazing answer/explanation of this behavior and why it happens [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/205930). In a nutshell, JavaScript does a lot of type casting and interesting things under the hood when you use the equality operator (`==`). More often, you'll probably want to be using the identity operator (`===`) as it performs stricter comparison and JavaScript doesn't attempt to do any type-casting or magic beneath the surface when using it.

Answer (score 2):

Double equals performs **type coercion**.  It'll attempt to convert each one to a common type before checking equality.  This is why it's recommended JavaScript developers always use triple equals(===) which performs a strict type equality comparison.

In this case, [] will be converted to an empty string which is considered falsy like the empty string it's being compared  to.  The same situation can be seen in the example below:

```
[5]==5
true
```